I can't open DevTools in a signed UWP WebView2 application
I am using a WebView2 control in an UWP application to render an online webpage. I want to open the DevTools for the debug purpose, but I can't.
I tried several ways to open DevTools but failed.

Press F12
Press Ctrl+Shift+I.
Right-click the page and then select Inspect
use the OpenDevToolsWindow API

I also tried WPF application, it's ok to open DevTools, only signed  UWP application can't. Is there a reason for this?
Thanks for your future answer.

Can it be opened using the API CoreWebView2.OpenDevToolsWindow?

I tried in UWP application, I can't. Not sure I need to add some additional configurations?

I tried the webview2 uwp sample provided by MS, I can't open the DevTools.
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/main/SampleApps/webview2_sample_uwp

I tried the sample and I can open it with "Ctrl+Shift+i" and click the DevTools button in the sample https://i.sstatic.net/A2n2rve8.png. Maybe you can check whether the DevTools is blocked by other windows. Check whether there is DevTools in the taskbar below.

It seems it's a known issue in a signed UWP.
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/3386

To use Microsoft Edge DevTools to debug a WebView2 WinUI 2 (UWP) app, use remote debugging. Remote debugging is necessary for WebView2 WinUI 2 (UWP) apps because currently, the built-in DevTools can't be launched inside a store-signed WebView2 WinUI 2 (UWP) app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/remote-debugging

This makes sense, you can convert it into an answer.

This is a known issue in a signed UWP.
To use Microsoft Edge DevTools to debug a WebView2 WinUI 2 (UWP) app, use remote debugging. Remote debugging is necessary for WebView2 WinUI 2 (UWP) apps because currently, the built-in DevTools can't be launched inside a store-signed WebView2 WinUI 2 (UWP) app.
Remote debugging
